# 'FIles are Empty' error when uploading files on Strapi Media Library

Tags: javascript, strapi

[image]

I am facing an issue with strapi upload provider.
Can somebody help here? Where is this issue comming from ?

Comment: If you don't provide more information about your use case, there is no possibility of helping you.

Comment: Did you install axios?

Comment: yes i did install axios

Answer (score 0):

this problem is related to the Axios version.

You have to downgrade it to early version and will work properly. You can edit your **package.json** and change the version:

```
...
"axios": "^0.21.4",
...
```

Then, remove your node_modules folder and run

> npm install

Comment: I don't think there is a need of axios, as Strapi work without axios also

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, I don't know how, But when I search on my old Project there no Axios installed, I think Strapi doesn't uses axios package at this time.

I just uninstall the axios package

```
npm uninstall axios
```

Delete `.cache, build and node_modules` folder

Re-install all the package

```
npm i
```

After Installation Run you code

Answer (score 0):

One of my dependency (3rd party e-mail provider to Strapi) has Axios version >1.0. After removed this package upload started working.

Answer (score 0):

The error has *nothing to do with axios* per se, as you can upload files to strapi using **Fetch API**, which is a native library in most of browsers.

I've also had this same problem ('Files are empty'). My problem was that I added a wrong parameter in **FormData.append**.
It should be FILES, in the plural `formData.append('files', file);`, and not in the singular `formData.append('file', file)`;

Here's the function I was using:

```
const handleUpload = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (file) {
      console.log('Uploading file...');

      const formData = new FormData();
      // The first parameter here in append should be FILES and not FILE
      // as I initially added. That was the mistake.
      formData.append('file', file);

      console.log(file);
      try {
        const result = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/upload/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.user.jwt}`,
          },
          body: formData,
        });

        const data = await result.json();

        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  };
```

For other examples, see Strapi documentation
https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/upload#upload-files

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue. I think it's related to the latest version of axios. To get around the issue I uninstalled axios, deleted the .cache and build directories, re-installed an earlier version of axios using "npm i axios@0" then I ran "npm run develop" then I refreshed the admin panel. After doing that, I was able to add files again.

Comment: I don't think there is a need of axios, as Strapi work without axios also

Comment: @gulshan-prajapati, It depends on how to use axios. For example, in Strapi you can implement a custom controller with logic where you need to make requests to external resources. In this case, axios may be appropriate. There are many other examples

Comment: @alexiuscrow Ya, depend, Got it :)